# Displaying data in tabular format in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am newbie to MVC 3.0 an LINQ to SQL. I am trying to display data from database in GRID type thing in MVC. I tried simple table but it's too static.

Code:

Controller:

using Testing_linq.Models;

```
namespace Testing_linq.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            var DataContext = new RegistrationDataContext();
            var Registration = DataContext.SelectRegistration_sp();

            return View(Registration);
        }
```

View:

```
@foreach(SelectRegistration_spResult reg in (IEnumerable<Object>)ViewData.Model)
{
    <tr>
     <td>@reg.userEmail </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Table is just for testing one record and i want all records to display in GRID which can be modified, sorted, deleted, updated etc.

Help me regarding this code.

Answer (score 0):

i think rather than building custom implementation of rendering a grid and implementing custom operations on grid like add,edit,update

you might have to look at some client side grid solutions like

[JQxGrid Widget](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/),[JQGrid Trirand](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

or MVC's own [WebGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx)

Comment: ok i used MVC Webgrid but it doesn't have UPDATE,DELETE, EDIT buttons

Comment: take a look at : http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/E2S9150113-Enhancing-WebGrid-with-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Operations.html